# Can I apply Newton-Raphson Method in the Systems of Trigonometric Equations?

Tags: numerical-methods

can I apply the Newton-Raphson Method in the given systems
$$
\left\{\begin{aligned}
A\sin x + B\cos y &= c\\
x + y &= d
\end{aligned}\right.?$$
Can you show me the derivation on getting the roots of this system using this method?
Thank You

Comment: Of course you can. Please clarify your question.

Comment: A trivial Google search taking less time than what you spent typing the question would have shown you [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method). Note, in particular, its [examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Examples) section.

Comment: and what is given?

Comment: This is a somewhat trivial example for a system of trigonometric equations, because you can easily substitute $y=d-x$ in the first equation and get a one-dimensional problem (assuming your unknowns are $x,y$)